# Call services in order and use params from result

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to use this Angular code in string order and get the returned values:

```
transaction: ITransaction = new Transaction();
merchant: IMerchant;

    const transactionid = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    if (!transactionid) {
      this.router.navigate(['panel', 'transactions']);
    }

    this.transactionService.get(transactionid)
      .subscribe(value => {
        if (value != null) {
          this.transaction = value;
        }
      });

    this.merchantService.get(this.transaction.merchant_id)
      .subscribe(value => {
        if (value != null) {
          this.merchant = value;
        }
      });

    console.log('value ' + this.merchant.name);
```

But I get null for merchant_id and the second request is not performed properly.

First I would like to to load transactionService.get(params['id']) using id from the http link. Second when the Object Transaction is loaded I would like to load get(transaction.merchant_id) using the unique_id loaded from the first request. I tried this:

```
this.route.params.pipe(
      tap( params => {
        if (params['id']) {
          return this.transactionService.get(params['id']);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }),
      switchMap( value => this.merchantService.get(value.merchant_id) )
    );
```

What is the proper wya to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) operator for cascading observables. Also, used the [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator to save the results in the class.

```js
this.transactionService.get(transactionid).pipe(
  tap(transaction => {
    this.transaction = transaction;
  }),
  mergeMap(transaction => {
    if (transaction != null) {
      return this.merchantService.get(transaction.merchant_id);
    }
    else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
).subscribe(merchant => {
  if (merchant != null) {
    this.merchant = merchant;
  }
});
```

Comment: For `console.log('value ' + this.merchant.name);` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` Any idea why?

Comment: It's an async statement. You should put `console.log(...)` in the `subscription` callback, so the data is ready when this statement is evaluated. Let me know if it fixes your problem.